# Vuejs 2 + form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, vue.js, vuejs2

Since vue-validator https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator is being ready for Vuejs 2, what is the best way to implement frontend validation?

UPDATE
I've found this awesome plugin
[Vee Validate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com)

Comment: Actually I have found this awesome plugin [Vee Validate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com)

Comment: I have tried [vue-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-form "vue-formquot;") and found it very userful

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a good way to implement front end validation for VueJS is to use [vuelidate](https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate).

It's very simple to use and powerful. It offers model-base validation, it means that it's what you define in data that is validated, so it's totally decoupled from the templates. It comes with common built-in validators for email , min and max length or required. And many others.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Since it's all ultimately Javascript, you could also use some of the existing Javascript validation libraries like [Parsely.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) or [Validate.js](https://validatejs.org/) to hook this up. One thing that's nice about the Validate.js library is that it's format could easily be stored in the global store if you're using Vuex:

```
var constraints = {
  creditCardNumber: {
    presence: true,
    format: {
      pattern: /^(34|37|4|5[1-5]).*$/,
      message: function(value, attribute, validatorOptions, attributes, globalOptions) {
        return validate.format("^%{num} is not a valid credit card number", {
          num: value
        });
      }
    },
    length: function(value, attributes, attributeName, options, constraints) {
      if (value) {
        // Amex
        if ((/^(34|37).*$/).test(value)) return {is: 15};
        // Visa, Mastercard
        if ((/^(4|5[1-5]).*$/).test(value)) return {is: 16};
      }
      // Unknown card, don't validate length
      return false;
    }
  },
  creditCardZip: function(value, attributes, attributeName, options, constraints) {
    if (!(/^(34|37).*$/).test(attributes.creditCardNumber)) return null;
    return {
      presence: {message: "is required when using AMEX"},
      length: {is: 5}
    };
  }
};
```

Then used as such:

```
validate({creditCardNumber: "4"}, constraints);
// => {"creditCardNumber": ["Credit card number is the wrong length (should be 16 characters)"]}

validate({creditCardNumber: "9999999999999999"}, constraints);
// => {"creditCardNumber": ["9999999999999999 is not a valid credit card number"]}

validate({creditCardNumber: "4242424242424242"}, constraints);
// => undefined

validate({creditCardNumber: "340000000000000"}, constraints);
// => {"creditCardZip": ["Credit card zip is required when using AMEX"]}
```

You could also hook those validate() functions to your component with something along the lines of `@blur=validate(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are not many choices. Take a look at [vue-awesome](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue) where you can find the most relevant libraries. There are 2 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using semantic-ui or its an option for you they have an amazing form validation plugin.

[semantic-ui-form-validation](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html)

I've used it with Vuejs and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I found this validator simple, flexible and well documented. It cover most scenarios of validating forms in Vue Js.

I used Jquery validator plugin in the past. Compared to that, this simple-vue-validator really stands out in its flexibility and its ability to validate both hard-coded and dynamically generated forms.

https://github.com/semisleep/simple-vue-validator

I used it extensively for my SaaS project and so far it has gone on really well.

Comment: Hi, is there a cdn for simple-vue-validator? Thanks.